# Is there a way to loop a regression by a subset?

Tags: r, loops

For a regression project, I created clusters of data via nbclust using kmeans. There are currently 4 clusters in this project, but if successful, the project could involve analyzing multiple US cities. Although I could build each regression manually, I would prefer to minimize the amount of code and, hence, the opportunity for coding errors.

The current model uses glm with multiple subsets and 10-15 different independent variables. I am currently building each cluster regression by hand.

```
Tulsa$Cluster <- Tulsa$Best.partition
#This creates a vector of clusters; there are currently 4 distinct clusters

summary(Tulsa_Cluster1 <- glm(formula = Tulsa$Result ~ Tulsa$FactorA Tulsa$FactorB + Tulsa$FactorC + Tulsa$FactorD + Tulsa$FactorE + Tulsa$FactorF, 
                              method = "glm.fit", family = gaussian(),subset = Tulsa$Cluster =="1"))

summary(Tulsa_Step <- stepAIC(Tulsa_Cluster1, direction = "both",trace = FALSE, 
                              scope=list(lower = ~ Tulsa_Cluster1$FactorA)))
```

My hope is to develop a regression by cluster which I can then summarize.

Comment: What part of `summary` lines will need to be looped?

Comment: Parfait - both statements. The first statement is the "base" regression for the cluster. The second statement is the stepwise regression that engages as soon as the initial regression is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider any of the following approaches using `unique`, `levels`, `split`, and `by` to iterate across unique values of *Cluster*:

**`unique`** + **`for`**

```
for (c in unique(Tulsa$Cluster)) {
   Tulsa_Cluster <- glm(formula = Result ~ FactorA + FactorB + FactorC + FactorD + FactorE + FactorF, 
                        data = Tulsa, method = "glm.fit", family = gaussian(), subset = Cluster == c)
   print(summary(Tulsa_Cluster))  # REQUIRED IN for LOOPS TO FOR CONSOLE OUTPUT

   Tulsa_Step <- stepAIC(Tulsa_Cluster, direction = "both", trace = FALSE, 
                         scope=list(lower = ~ Tulsa_Cluster$FactorA))
   print(summary(Tulsa_Step))     # REQUIRED IN for LOOPS TO FOR CONSOLE OUTPUT
}
```

**`levels`** + **`for`**

```
for (c in levels(factor(Tulsa$Cluster))) {
   Tulsa_Cluster <- glm(formula = Result ~ FactorA + FactorB + FactorC + FactorD + FactorE + FactorF, 
                        data = Tulsa, method = "glm.fit", family = gaussian(), subset = Cluster == c)
   print(summary(Tulsa_Cluster))

   Tulsa_Step <- stepAIC(Tulsa_Cluster, direction = "both", trace = FALSE, 
                         scope=list(lower = ~ Tulsa_Cluster$FactorA))
   print(summary(Tulsa_Step))
}
```

---

Below two returns a named list of objects.

**`split`** + **`lapply`**  *(no subset arg)*

```
data_list <- split(Tulsa, Tulsa$Cluster)

model_list <- lapply(data_list, function(sub_df) {
   Tulsa_Cluster <- glm(formula = Result ~ FactorA + FactorB + FactorC + FactorD + FactorE + FactorF, 
                        data = sub_df, method = "glm.fit", family = gaussian())

   Tulsa_Step <- stepAIC(Tulsa_Cluster, direction = "both", trace = FALSE, 
                         scope=list(lower = ~ Tulsa_Cluster$FactorA))

   # RETURN BOTH SUMMARIES INTO LIST
   return(list(Tulsa_Cluster, Tulsa_Step))
})
```

**`by`** *(no subset arg)*

```
model_list <- by(Tulsa, Tulsa$Cluster, function(sub_df) {
   Tulsa_Cluster <- glm(formula = Result ~ FactorA + FactorB + FactorC + FactorD + FactorE + FactorF, 
                        data = sub_df, method = "glm.fit", family = gaussian())

   Tulsa_Step <- stepAIC(Tulsa_Cluster, direction = "both", trace = FALSE, 
                         scope=list(lower = ~ Tulsa_Cluster$FactorA))

   # RETURN BOTH SUMMARIES INTO LIST
   return(list(Tulsa_Cluster, Tulsa_Step))
})
```

Comment: Thank you! This is amazing and I really appreciate your help.